# I just cloned my HDD to my SSD with Clonezilla and my boot time is much slower than on my HDD, can anyone help?

Tags: boot, startup, ssd, clone

I did a partition to partition clone. I have a Samsung 840 Evo. I've looked around, and here's my [dmesg report](http://pastebin.com/r7zLszHt).

Comment: 88 sec delay at line 873 -- virtual box problem?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to format the SSD and do a BACKUP of the HDD to some external drive. Then reinstall the OS completely onto your SSD without cloning. Then go to your system settings and do a backup restore from the external drive. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable NCQ by parameter before booting, as it seems to be some compatibility issue that makes the kernel to disable "queued TRIM support", as reported via Dmesg at:

> [    2.344002] ata1.00: disabling queued TRIM support"

Check this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1591293 It seems that it takes many seconds to the kernel to decide to disable NCQ.

If you´re using Grub bootloader, just try to add this parameter: `libata.force=noncq` to the line that runs the kernel.  (You can edit the boot commands for just one time by pressing `e` at grub menu)

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung 840 Evo had an issues that made it very slow to load older files and a new firmware was released. It fixed the slowness of my 840 Evo. Make sure your SSD has the latest firmware installed.

http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html